# Setting an MSBuild property to a file version

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I'm installing a toolset and I use the `$(Registry:Path@Value)` syntax to read the path to the compiler executable and set a property containing this value.  However, in order to properly set up the search paths that the executable needs, I need to read the file version of this executable.  I've seen examples of using a Target to do this and putting a Task in the target that invokes `GetAssemblyVersion`, but I want something more like a property function, because I want to initialize this before a build has even been run.  The user should be able to go into the Project Settings and see the value I've determined as part of their include path.  So what I'd really like is something like this:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CompilerExe>$(Registry:Path@Value)</CompilerExe>
    <CompilerVersion>$(GetFileVersion:$(CompilerExe))</CompilerVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Obviously the syntax above doesn't work, but is there any way I can do something like this?